# How to check erros in my Ionic 4 project?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm developing an App (Using Ionic 4, Angular, Typescript) that records Audios and play afterwards. For some reason when I test on the device, after the user allow the app to use Local Storage and the Mic, it chrashes with no erros.
Is there an way to have a Log of what is going on? I'll leave my .html and .ts files.

audios.page.html

```
 <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-button expand="full" (click)="capturarAudio()">Gravar áudio</ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-list>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let arquivo of mediaFiles" tappable (click)="play(arquivo)" text-wrap>
    {{ file.name }}
    <p>{{file.size / 1000 / 1000 | number }} MB </p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

audios.page.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MediaCapture } from '@ionic-native/media-capture/ngx';
    import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
    import { Media, MediaObject  } from '@ionic-native/media/ngx';
    import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
    import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

    const MEDIA_FILES_KEY = 'mediafiles';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-audios',
      templateUrl: './audios.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./audios.page.scss'],
    })
    export class AudiosPage implements OnInit {

      mediaFiles = [];
      constructor(private mediaCapture: MediaCapture, private storage: Storage, private media: Media, private file: File) { 


      }

      ionViewDidLoad(){

        this.storage.get(MEDIA_FILES_KEY).then(res => {
          this.mediaFiles = JSON.parse(res) || [];
        });
      }

      capturarAudio(){
        this.mediaCapture.captureAudio().then( res => {
          this.storeMediaFiles(res);
        })
      }

      play(myFile){
        console.log('play', myFile);
        if (myFile.name.indexOf('.wav') > -1){
          const audioFile: MediaObject = this.media.create(myFile.localURL)
          audioFile.play();
        }
      }

      storeMediaFiles(files){
        console.log('storage:', files);
        this.storage.get(MEDIA_FILES_KEY).then(res => {
          if (res) {
            let arr = JSON.parse(res);
            arr = arr.concat(files);
            this.storage.set(MEDIA_FILES_KEY, JSON.stringify(arr))
          } else {
            this.storage.set(MEDIA_FILES_KEY, JSON.stringify(files))
          }
          this.mediaFiles = this.mediaFiles.concat(files);
        })

      }

        ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

EDIT1: With Logcat I get this error:

```
E/PluginManager: Uncaught exception from plugin
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1899)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1589)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4229)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.startActivityForResult(CordovaActivity.java:343)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4187)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterfaceImpl.startActivityForResult(CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:68)
        at org.apache.cordova.mediacapture.Capture.captureAudio(Capture.java:234)
        at org.apache.cordova.mediacapture.Capture.execute(Capture.java:132)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:98)
        at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
        at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What kind of device are you testing on? For Android you could use Logcat to get more details. For iOS you could use XCode to see more details.

Comment: I'm testing on my Moto X Play, I'll try on Android Studio with Logcat

Comment: Here is solution: https://medium.com/@coderonfleek/debugging-an-ionic-android-app-using-chrome-dev-tools-6e139b79e8d2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a look at the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions) for Android permissions you will find the following steps.

To find the permissions you require, have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html?hl=zh-tw). You then use that in the below code. The android permissions has to be called right before you use that resource since Android API >=26.

---

### Installation

Run the following in your console:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-android-permissions
npm install @ionic-native/android-permissions
```

---

### Usage

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';


constructor(private androidPermissions: AndroidPermissions) { }

...

this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA).then(
  result => console.log('Has permission?',result.hasPermission),
  err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA)
);

this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA, this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.GET_ACCOUNTS]);
```

Comment: But this is just for Camera permission, right? I'm not trying to use the camera.

Comment: Look at the second link in my answer called `here` it has all the permissions that you can request. There are too many to post here that is why I linked to it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!